# Websocket callback requires interaction in order for UI to react to state update in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js, supabase

```
channel
         .on("broadcast", { event: "cursor-pos" }, async ({ payload }) => {
            console.log(payload);
            setFormations((formations) => {
               let newFormations = applyChangeset(formations, payload[0].changes);
               return newFormations;
            });
         })
```

The code above subscribes to the web socket channel and listens for all messages. Everytime it receives a payload, react is able to console log it just fine.

However, when it runs the setFormations state updater. The UI doesn't react to the state update immediately.

Instead it only changes the UI after I interact with the app in some way (clicking or typing something). Everywhere else in the app, the state updating works just fine, it is only in the websocket callback from supabase.

Comment: The only assumption I can make from this is that `applyChangeset` is mutating formations instead of creating a new object. If you mutate the reference remains the same and React uses a reference comparison to determine when props / state have updated. TLDR same object, no update.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that react did not "see" a state update because it referenced the same value?

```
  setFormations((formations) => {
               let newFormations = applyChangeset(formations, payload[0].changes);
               return [...newFormations]  //return newFormations; adding the spread operator worked
            });
```